# Jackson - Not deserialize string "null" to null object

Tags: java, jackson

I'm using Jackson 2.6.3 to deserialize JSON strings to Java objects and I have a piece of code below:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
HashMap<?, ?> result = objectMapper.readValue("null", HashMap.class);
// result is null 
System.out.println(result == null);
```

I wonder if Jackson has any configurations to not convert `String` `"null"` to `null` object but throw an exception?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28355891/configure-jackson-to-throw-an-exception-when-a-field-is-missing ?

Comment: They are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Jackson very well but what about a simple method, maybe in your UtilClass, like this:

```
public <T> T deserialize(final ObjectMapper objectMapper, final String jsonString, final Class<T> yourClass) throws Exception 
{
   if(jsonString == null || jsonString.equalsIgnoreCase("null"))
      throw new Exception(); //maybe change the type's exception
   return objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, yourClass);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's simple, but if you are deserializing from a byte array, you have to do a little bit more to pre-check the input. It's not so convenient.